# How long will bottled beer last?

Tags: beer, bottling, bottle-conditioning, spoilage

How long will bottled beer last without refrigeration?

Comment: Just pulled out a 5 yr old pale ale & it's awesome! Forgot about them & there's another 10 longnecks. Stored under the house (dry) in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Ive yet to make my 1st brew. Was worried about storage and spoilage, as I drive semi. Im out 2 - 4 weeks at a time and was afraid would just sit there and go bad. I enjoy making wine but am gearing up for my 1st beer brew. Thanks agian

Answer (score 14):

It depends on the beer and the storage conditions.  To start, the stronger and hoppier the beer, the longer it will keep.  For instance, a hefeweizen won't keep as long as a barleywine.  The temperature is also important.  Generally, cooler is better.  The main thing is to avoid excessively high (85+) temps.  Avoiding temp swings helps, but it's mainly high temps that are your enemy.  I've kept 1.100+ bbers like Am. BW and RIS for 10 years at normal room temps and the age just improves their complexity.  Of course, you must have excellent sanitation, too.

Comment: And keep them in the dark as much as possible!

Comment: Temperature swings don't matter at all.  See: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/what-effect-does-cooling-then-warming-have-on-finished-beer

Answer (score 3):

Like Brewchez and Denny have said, avoiding high temperatures and light are the most important parts.  I've found that a lot of my "muddy" beers have cleaned up after around a year of storage in a dark ~65F closet.  Case in point, I had a pumpkin ale that was neigh undrinkable two years ago, and almost an entire case remained in the closet.  This fall I dug it out again and found that all the "pumpkin pie spice" flavors that they always talk about had melded into something surprisingly drinkable.  I wouldn't go more than a year or two for low-gravity beers, but I'd say leave it in there, forget about it, and you might be surprised by how well things turn out.

Answer (score 3):

BrewYourOwn magazine ([Mar/Apr 2011](http://www.byo.com/stories/issue/list/issues/280-marapr-2011)) just did an experiment on how storage temps affect home brew.

Their main finding was just as Denny said: high temps will degrade the beer and cause off-flavors. In this experiment the "high temps" were >100° (like in an attic during the summer) for weeks at a time.

"Room temp" storage was almost indistinguishable from "Cellar temp" storage.